# Trouble in switching from silent mode

Tags: android

I am  Doing a program which detects the incoming call and if the app is in the silent mode it switch to general mode and rings.
I had used a Broadcast receiver to listen the incoming calls and a service starts from it.

The broadcast receiver I am using is

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
            Log.i("MyApp","Silent mode");
            Intent IncomingNumberIntent = new Intent(context,RingOnSilent.class);  
  //             IncomingNumberIntent.putExtra("PhoneNumber", phonenumber);
             context.startService(IncomingNumberIntent); 
            break;
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
            Log.i("MyApp","Vibrate mode");
            break;
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
            Log.i("MyApp","Normal mode");
            break;
    }
}
```

And from there starts a service,

```
     @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
am = (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
super.onStart(intent, startId);
}
```

The problem is on the first time after installation it switching to normal but not ringing.
But after that it rings. Can Anybody tell me whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should call "super" first in your service. Like this:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onStart(intent, startId); 
      am = (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    }
```

Otherwise your service might not be ready yet when calling the other stuff. Super should always be called first to "initialize" stuff from its parent class.